# Benchmarking of a scheme in charm-crypto?

Tags: python, charm-crypto

Looking at the following scheme in Charm Crypto [abenc_yct14](https://github.com/JHUISI/charm/blob/dev/charm/schemes/abenc/abenc_yct14.py) and i am trying to understand the use of looping for the benchmark function (line 134). Seems to me that the algorithms are run multiple times with the total time given as the result. Is that a normal approach as I expected that if it is run multiple times then the average would be a more adequate result.

Comment: Given that you'd be dividing through by the same number and ending up with the same *ratios*, why bother?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I was looking at it from the point of view of the results. If you want to show the time an algorithm takes, wouldnt it make more sense for the time to be less? Or does it have to do with the scheme implementation?